# ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

so i know that there´s a lot of questions like that, but none had answered my questions and solved my problem. So, I am with this problem for about a week and I can´t solve it! I am really new to ruby on rails, but i´ve tried tried everything. I have this (ActionController::ParameterMissing:
  param is missing or the value is empty:opinion) and I don´t know how to fix it. There´s all the code (I am newbie so it is really simple) :

Opinion Controller :

```
    class OpinionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @opinion = Opinion.new
  end

  def create
    @opinion = Opinion.new(opi_params)
    @opinion.save
    redirect_to @opinion
  end

  def show
    @opinion = Opinion.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def opi_params
        params.require(:opinion).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

New :

```
<h1>Opinions</h1>

<%= form_for :opinion do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Create an option" %> 
<% end %>
```

DB :

```
    class CreateOpinions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :opinions do |t|
      t.string :body
    end
  end
end
```

Show :

```
    <h1>Your Opinions:</h1>
<div>
    <%= @opinion.body %>
</div>
```

PLEASE HELP ME! I am getting crazy because i cannot solve it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h1>Opinions</h1>

<%= form_for @opinion do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Create an option" %> 
<% end %>
```

Change `:opinion` to the instance variable `@opinion`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may also occur when the form is submitted with the field `body` empty if it is your case change the strong parameters to
`params.fetch(:opinion, {}).permit(:body)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend dropping a debugger like `pry` or `byebug` right between `def create` and `@opinion = Opinion.new(opi_params)` and seeing what `params` is coming in. You might be missing `opinion`, which will trigger the `ParameterMissing` error.

Also, are you getting this error through the browser or through your test? If you are getting this error from your test, it might be your set up.

In the meantime, try `params.permit(:body)` in your `opi_params` method.